# How to group mean values of a column after pivoting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following lines of SQL code which are part of a stored procedure:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName) 
        FROM [dbo].[vw_Imported_Files] with(nolock)
        WHERE [vw_Imported_Files].RF_GUID_ID = @sGUID 
AND [vw_Imported_Files].RF_IsEnabled = 1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @query2 = 'SELECT  ROUND(AVG(CAST(RD_Axis AS FLOAT)),3) AS RD_Axis
,' + @cols + ' FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DenseRank ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
AS RowNumber, rd.* FROM 
   (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rd.RD_RF_ID) AS DenseRank
    ,rd.RD_Axis AS RD_Axis
    ,rd.DN_Values AS DN_Values
    ,rd.RF_FileName AS RF_FileName
  FROM #TEMP rd
  WHERE rd.RD_GUID_ID = ' + @sGUID + '
  AND rd.RD_IsEnabled = 1

 ) rd  
    ) rn 
    pivot 
        (
            max(DN_Values)
            for RF_FileName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p
GROUP BY RD_Axis, ' + @cols + ' '

execute (@query2)
```

Actually, this query (@query2) results as shown in the following table.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   0       |   NULL                | NULL              | 0,996573652935408|
|   0       |   NULL                | 1,00053003751428  | NULL             |
|   0       |   0,999843071844672   | NULL              | NULL             |
|   0,052   |   NULL                | NULL              | 0,992999630825293|
|   0,052   |   1,02368347072563    | NULL              | NULL             |
|   0,053   |   NULL                | 0,992674427713489 | NULL             |
|   0,104   |   NULL                | NULL              | 0,998690236570867|
|   0,104   |   NULL                | 0,996645964692132 | NULL             |
|   0,105   |   0,989815140503533   | NULL              | NULL             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do, is to clear all the `NULL` values by grouping the `Average` of the RD_Axis values that have the same DenseRank value. In the current instance, the DenseRank increases every 3 rows. So, the outcome that I want has to look like as depicted in the next table.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0        |  0,999843071844672    |  1,00053003751428  | 0,996573652935408|
| 0,052    |  1,02368347072563     |  0,992674427713489 | 0,992999630825293|
| 0,104    |  0,989815140503533    |  0,996645964692132 | 0,998690236570867|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope to find my inquiry clear. Could you please help me to figure out how to transform the above SQL code in order for me to get the desirable result?

Comment: Please explain *what* you are trying to do, not *how* you tried to do this. You don't need string concatenations and XML to pivot, unpivot or calculate aggregates. Without the schema of the original view it's impossible to guess what is being asked, or how it can be solved in a clean way

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a new column variable that gets the MAX(dynamicColumn) value for your outer select.. that way you can remove the GROUP BY at the end.

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName) 
        FROM [dbo].[vw_Imported_Files] with(nolock)
        WHERE [vw_Imported_Files].RF_GUID_ID = @sGUID 
AND [vw_Imported_Files].RF_IsEnabled = 1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @maxCols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', MAX(' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName)
        FROM [dbo].[vw_Imported_Files] with(nolock)
        WHERE [vw_Imported_Files].RF_GUID_ID = @sGUID 
AND [vw_Imported_Files].RF_IsEnabled = 1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @query2 = '
    SELECT  ROUND(AVG(CAST(RD_Axis AS FLOAT)),3) AS RD_Axis
    ,' + @maxCols + ' 
    FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DenseRank ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
                AS RowNumber, rd.* 
         FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rd.RD_RF_ID) AS DenseRank
                    ,rd.RD_Axis AS RD_Axis
                    ,rd.DN_Values AS DN_Values
                    ,rd.RF_FileName AS RF_FileName
               FROM #TEMP rd
               WHERE rd.RD_GUID_ID = ' + @sGUID + ' AND rd.RD_IsEnabled = 1

            ) rd  
        ) rn 
    pivot 
        (
            max(DN_Values)
            for RF_FileName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p 
    GROUP BY DenseRank'

execute (@query2)
```

This can probably be done without using PIVOT and be a lot cleaner by using aggregates with CASE expressions

Comment: the code that you mentioned estimates the overall average value of the RD_Axis column and returns the outcome in one line. What I want is to group the "closer" RD_Axis (between each other - based on its DenseRank) and to estimate their mean values. Please take a look at the second table that I have created above.

Comment: Im not sure what that value looks like since you're excluding it from your query results.. you might just need to group by that value, which i'm guessing is `RowNumber`, or you may need to select the `DenseRank` value also and group by that

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the result that I was looking for with the following code.

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName) 
        FROM [dbo].[vw_Imported_Files] with(nolock)
        WHERE [vw_Imported_Files].RF_GUID_ID = @sGUID and [vw_Imported_Files].RF_IsEnabled = 1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @maxCols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', MAX(' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME([vw_Imported_Files].RF_FileName)
    FROM [dbo].[vw_Imported_Files] with(nolock)
    WHERE [vw_Imported_Files].RF_GUID_ID = @sGUID AND [vw_Imported_Files].RF_IsEnabled = 1
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

SET @query2 = '
SELECT  ' + @maxCols + ' 
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DenseRank ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
            AS RowNumber, rd.* 
     FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rd.RD_RF_ID) AS DenseRank
                ,rd.RD_Axis AS RD_Axis
                ,rd.DN_Values AS DN_Values
                ,rd.RF_FileName AS RF_FileName
           FROM #TEMP rd
           WHERE rd.RD_GUID_ID = ' + @sGUID + ' AND rd.RD_IsEnabled = 1

        ) rd  
    ) rn 
pivot 
    (
        max(DN_Values)
        for RF_FileName in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p 
GROUP BY RowNumber ORDER BY RowNumber'

execute (@query2)
```

At first I generated the outcome that I wanted (@query2) and then I got the average of the RD_Axis values with another query (both ordered by Rownumber asc). Then I linked them with a `UNION ALL` statement. Btw, thanks for the fresh perspective on my issue because I had been stuck for hours.